# Set HTML margin to last line

Tags: html, printing, margin

I have to print an HTML page. As I use a continous sheet, I need to set the print margin to the last line in the page so that paper is not wasted. Is there any HTML tag/css property to set the printer margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the printer options using CSS Media Queries

```
@media print {
  /* all the properties here would be applied to printed form only */
}
```

This way you can change the display of the HTML elements on the screen and the printed form.

To minimize the page usage you can shorten the font-size, you can minimize the margins, you can reduce the paddings etc. Like this:

```
@media print {
   font-size: .8em;
   padding: 1px; /* or none if there is 1px padding */
   margin: 0; /* or just the margin-bottom to be set as 0 */
}
```

The rest is upto you. You can change all the properties so that they fit in the page size.

Comment: I know the print property. But how do I make the print to stop after the last line? So that there is no unwanted printing of free space?

Comment: Once you just remove the bottom margin, and the space under the parapraph, how would be there a white space? Just remove the properties that are un necessary for the printed format! :) You'll get it to work..

Comment: Do you mean to say that giving margin:0; will stop printing at the last line and print no extra white space, to fill the default page size?

Comment: Nope! I am saying you should remove all the margins that are at the end of the page, and lessen the screen size. CSS won't be able to stop the print execution if there is no more text below. That's not what CSS would do..

Comment: Thats what am asking. How to remove margins at the end of the page?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, by using `margin-bottom: 0` -_- use this at the body element in the media print...

Comment: body element in @media print?? Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this so please bear with me

Comment: Aha @AswinMurugesh bhai, don't mention, since you're new to this I have written a tutorial for you to start at: http://basicsofwebdevelopment.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/css3-media-queries/ Go to this blog post, and learn how you can use CSS3 media query to change the document look and style :) Good luck :)